# What happens if I ramp temperature too fast?

Tags: temperature, belgian

I'm brewing a Duvel Belgian golden strong.  Chilled my wort to 64°F and pitched my yeast.  My plan was to raise the temperature 3 degrees a day to 82°F.  Today (day 2) ambient temperature rose into the 80s, and my fermentation rose to 76°F. I've moved to a cooler location, and temperature is stabilizing.

Did I ruin my brew by raising the temperature too quickly?

Comment: No worries, your beer will be fine. If you don't go to a temperature the yeast cannot take, it shouldn't matter too much how quickly you get to that temperature.

Answer (score 4):

No, you did not. Belgian yeast usually don't mind fast temperature increase. Just be sure not to exceed max temperature suggested by yeast supplier.

And just by the way, the one time I had temperature raising too fast was with Belgian yeast, too. Similar with the people I talked with. Seems that these strains simply like to surprise us with heat production.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that raising too fast was the issue, but raising too soon could be.  You' be better off waiting 72-96 hours before raising the temp.  Simply put, your situation is not critical but it could be better.  Fortunately the Duvel yeast throws relatively few esters so you may be OK.